# Access a specific list from a set of lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, machine-learning

```
def fit(x,y, lrate):
    cost_ = []
    n_iterations_ = []
    w_ = np.zeros((x.shape[1], 1))
    m = x.shape[0]
    n_iterations = 10
    i = 0
    while i < n_iterations:
        y_pred = np.dot(x, w_)
        residuals = y_pred - y
        gradient_vector = np.dot(x.T, residuals)
        w_ -= (lrate / m) * gradient_vector *(-2)
        cost = np.sum((residuals ** 2)) / m
        cost_.append(cost)
        n_iterations_.append(i)
        i+=1
    return w_, cost_, n_iterations_

learning_rates = [1E-6, 1E-5, 1E-4, 1E-3, 1E-2, 1E-1]

for i in range(len(learning_rates)):
    lr = fit(X_train, y_train,learning_rates[i])
    print(lr[1])
```

When i run the above code i get the following output

```
[576.1537376237624, 576.1545609827812, 576.155384359385, 576.1562077535746, 576.1570311653502, 576.1578545947123, 576.1586780416611, 576.1595015061973, 576.1603249883211, 576.1611484880332]
[576.1537376237624, 576.161971609612, 576.1702073541688, 576.1784448578509, 576.1866841210765, 576.1949251442638, 576.2031679278315, 576.2114124721976, 576.219658777781, 576.2279068450003]
[576.1537376237624, 576.2361170484683, 576.3186725320611, 576.4014044933067, 576.48431335199, 576.5673995289181, 576.6506634459224, 576.7341055258611, 576.8177261926215, 576.9015258711238]
[576.1537376237624, 576.9814884918198, 577.8270339789372, 578.6907997611174, 579.5732219342204, 580.4747472702393, 581.3958334798867, 582.3369494816455, 583.2985756774436, 584.281204235115]
[576.1537376237624, 584.826908404254, 595.4739343028948, 608.5938411910076, 624.8145782295895, 644.9264682232412, 669.9243443735022, 701.0606295042115, 739.9121998096105, 788.4646133533605]
[576.1537376237624, 702.4516554203875, 1277.1568412503211, 4042.0736136112046, 17595.436653069664, 84433.45249482371, 414672.7920504886, 2047336.072196413, 10120573.694524828, 50043771.857434966]
```

I want to access the individual lists from the output so my desired output is

```
[576.1537376237624, 576.1545609827812, 576.155384359385, 576.1562077535746, 576.1570311653502, 576.1578545947123, 576.1586780416611, 576.1595015061973, 576.1603249883211, 576.1611484880332]
```

Comment: you want to access the rows of `lr[1]` or of `lr ` ?

Comment: i want to access rows of lr[1]

Comment: see my answer and let me know

Comment: Share your desired output please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
learning_rates = [1E-6, 1E-5, 1E-4, 1E-3, 1E-2, 1E-1]

all_results=[]
for i in range(len(learning_rates)):
    lr = fit(X_train, y_train,learning_rates[i])
    all_results.append(lr[0])
```

Then:

```
for i in range(len(all_results)):
    print(all_results[i]) # prints row by row
```

Comment: It is giving me output : 576.1537376237624
576.1537376237624
576.1537376237624
576.1537376237624
576.1537376237624
576.1537376237624

Comment: which is not what i desire

Comment: type(lr) = <class 'tuple'>

Comment: can you upload the `lr` file or post the data?

Comment: sure. I have uploaded the code in my notebook :   https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Hy5neEwe8pduIVpYLgUk-fKIIDER9ueb

Comment: It is giving me an error : IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: I cannot download your code. please upload just the `lr`

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you Makis. You are the best!